# Conditional check in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I want to check whether a possibly mandatory field is filled in using selenium. I would very much prefer to do this using the IDE rather than exporting to code.

To be more specific, I want to make sure that a post code field is filled in if the value of the country drop down list is 'United Kingdom'. The post code field can be left blank if the drop down list is set to anything else.

If the consensus is that I have to export and do the test in code, then I will, but I would be a lot happier if I could sort this out just through the IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, Selenium-IDE does not offer any flow control functionality by default. However, the [Flow Control](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flow-control/) plugin introduces a few new commands - `while`, `gotoIf`, `label` and the `...andWait` variants. Using these, you should be able to check the currently selected value in the dropdown menu, and jump past a `verify` command if the value is not "United Kingdom".

Fair warning; it's not the easiest thing in the world to work with. For anything beyond very basic flow control, you'd probably be better off exporting to code anyway. But, it's an option for when you really want to push the IDE!

Comment: Ok, thank you. Is there some decent documentation for Flow control that I can look at?

Comment: Beyond [very basic blog posts](http://selenium.polteq.com/en/use-the-flow-control-user-extension/), nothing that I've been able to locate. As I said, not the easiest thing in the world to work with ;)

Comment: This does seem to do pretty much everything that I need, so thank you very much kind sir!